# How to modify dynamic query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which stores SQL queries. I am reading that and executing it by using `EXECUTE sp_executesql`. I was wondering that, if I want to modify this query, how can I do that?

If I have to add a variable in the end, I can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @var NVARCHAR(20)

SET @sql1 = (SELECT Query FROM Table WHERE ID = 123)
SET @var = ' AND CONDITION2'

PRINT @sql1 + @var
```

Result:

```
UPDATE Table SET VALUE1 WHERE CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2
```

But if I want to add something in between, I'm not sure how to do that.

Query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = (SELECT Query FROM Table WHERE ID = 123)
PRINT @sql
```

Actual result:

```
UPDATE Table SET VALUE1 WHERE CONDITION1
```

Expected:

```
UPDATE TOP (100) Table SET VALUE1 WHERE CONDITION1
```

Comment: Without some actual details nobody else knows how to do this either. Mostly because we have no idea what you are trying to do. You should start with table definitions and sample data. Then include what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your original query to include a placeholder

```
 SET @sql =  'UPDATE {0} Table SET VALUE1 WHERE CONDITION1';
 SET @top_condition = 'TOP(100)';
 SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, 
                    '{0}', 
                    CONVERT(varchar(max), @top_condition)
                   );
```

You also can remove the top option if you want it

```
 SET @top_condition = '';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.